# Does ELF EI_CLASS endianness always match the target processor endianness

Tags: elf, endianness

I'd like to know if ELF EI_CLASS endianness always match the target processor endianness ?

When reading the ELF format I interpret ELFDATA2LSB and ELFDATA2MSB as the endianness of the ELF a.out file format. Most of the time it match the target processor endianness. But on bi-endian architecture, can a a.out be little endian while the processor is running in big endian mode (or vice versa)